# How to calculate $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}((-2^x+1)^{\sin(x)})$

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I solve the following limit problem?

> $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}((-2^x+1)^{\sin(x)})$

I can't find any approach to this one, although it really doesn't look that bad. Somehow my intuition tells me, that this one could turn out to be harder to calculate than expected.

I don't need to mention, that you cannot simply plug in 0, because $(-2^0+1)^{\sin(0)} = 0^0$.

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Since $\exp(X)$ is a continuous function you can write your limit as:
$$
\lim\limits_{x \to 0}((-2^x+1)^{\sin(x)})=\exp\left[\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\sin x \log (1-2^x)\right) \right]=\exp\left[\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{ \log (1-2^x)}{\csc x}\right) \right]
$$
and now you can use L'Hopital rule.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to note that as $x \to 0^{+}$ we have $2^{x} > 1$ and hence $(1 - 2^{x}) < 0$ and therefore the expression $(-2^{x} + 1)^{\sin x}$ does not make sense in the context of real numbers.

Hence we can consider only $x \to 0^{-}$. It then makes sense to switch the variables and use $x = -y$ so that $y \to 0^{+}$. The function $f(x)$ is now changed to $$f(x) = (1 - 2^{x})^{\sin x} = (1 - 2^{-y})^{-\sin y} = \frac{1}{(1 - 2^{-y})^{\sin y}}$$ If $L$ is the desired limit then we can proceed as follows
\begin{align}
\log L &= \log\left(\lim_{x \to 0^{-}}f(x)\right)\notag\\
&= \lim_{y \to 0^{+}}\log\left(\frac{1}{(1 - 2^{-y})^{\sin y}}\right)\text{ (via continuity of log)}\notag\\
&= -\lim_{y \to 0^{+}}\sin y\log(1 - 2^{-y})\notag\\
&= -\lim_{y \to 0^{+}}\frac{\sin y}{y}\cdot y\cdot\left\{\log(2^{y} - 1) - y\log 2\right\}\notag\\
&= -\lim_{y \to 0^{+}} (y\log(2^{y} - 1) - y^{2}\log 2)\notag\\
&= -\lim_{y \to 0^{+}} y\log(2^{y} - 1)\notag\\
&= -\lim_{y \to 0^{+}} \frac{y}{2^{y} - 1}\cdot(2^{y} - 1)\log(2^{y} - 1)\notag\\
&= -\frac{1}{\log 2}\lim_{y \to 0^{+}} (2^{y} - 1)\log(2^{y} - 1)\notag\\
&= -\frac{1}{\log 2}\lim_{z \to 0^{+}} z\log z\text{ (putting }z = 2^{y} - 1)\notag\\
&= -\frac{1}{\log 2}\cdot 0\notag\\
&= 0\notag
\end{align}
Hence $L = 1$. Here in the above derivation we have used the following standard limits $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1,\, \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{a^{x} - 1}{x} = \log a,\, \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}x\log x = 0$$